# How do I configure the name of a Windows service upon installation (or easily at compile time)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-installer

I've created a Windows service in C#, installed it on a server and it is running fine.

Now I want to install the same service again, but running from a different working directory, having a different config file etc. Thus, I would like to have *two* (or more) instances of the same service running simultaneously. 
Initially, this isn't possible since the installer will complain that there's already a service with the given name installed.

I can overcome this by changing my code, setting the `ServiceBase.ServiceName` property to a new value, then recompiling and running InstallUtil.exe again. However, I would much prefer if I could set the service name at install-time, i.e. ideally I would do something like

> InstallUtil.exe /i
>   /servicename="MyService Instance 2"
>   MyService.exe

If this isn't achievable (I very much doubt it), I would like to be able to inject the service name when I build the service. I thought it might be possible to use some sort of build event, use a clever msbuild or nant trick or something along those lines, but I haven't got a clue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't given your service the abbility to execute the business logic in n-threads for n-config files? Thus saving the multiple instances issue from the start?

Comment: Hmmm, that might be a good point. But the service was created a year ago, way before I realized that I would like to be able to run multiple instances, so the application isn't really architected appropriately. 
However, I've found a solution and will post it in a sec.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I tried accessing a configuration using

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(string exePath)
```

in the installer, but couldn't get it to work.

Instead I decided to use `System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` in the installer like this:

```
string[] commandlineArgs = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

string servicename;
string servicedisplayname;
ParseServiceNameSwitches(
    commandlineArgs, 
    out servicename, 
    out servicedisplayname);

serviceInstaller.ServiceName = servicename;
serviceInstaller.DisplayName = servicedisplayname;
```

Now I can install my services using

> InstallUtil.exe /i
>   InstallableService.dll
>   /servicename="myserviceinstance_2"
>   /servicedisplayname="My Service
>   Instance 2"

I wrote up a more elaborate explanation [here](http://www.runeibsen.dk/?p=153).

Comment: Look at question and answer to get perfect solution for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516701/how-to-get-windows-service-name-from-app-config

Comment: Please could you post your "more elaborate explanation" somewhere? Your link doesn't work and I'd like to read it

Answer (score 4):

You can't pass this in as a command line arg, since InstallUtil doesn't provide the right hooks for that.

However, you can make your service installer read the ServiceName from a config file.  If you [look at some code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C) for a typical ServiceInstaller, you'll see it's just a matter of having the appropriate DisplayName and ServiceName properties setup at runtime.  These could easily be read from a configuration file instead of being hard-coded.

Comment: Really? I've tried reading these values from the ServiceExeName.config file during installation of the windows service and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` the class `Installer` has a property called `Context` from which you can access command line arguments passed to InstallUtil structured in a nice `StringDictionary`.