# ServiceInstaller and "service already exists" 1001 error

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have an application with a project- and serviceinstaller in it. The installation usually works fine except in some cases when installed through PSEXEC remotely.

I wonder, where in the code I can intercept and check if the specific service is already installed and either, depending of best option, uninstall it or skip the current installation of service (but still continue with the overall install).

Comment: Not sure if this might provide some insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835422

Answer (score 0):

You can try uninstalling it unconditionally every time before you install.

Comment: The problem is that the installation starts when double clicking on a shortcut (to other application in same install). Somehow Windows detects that installation needs to be installed again some way. I am not on what level this happens if it inside serviceinstaller code or what but I would like to intercept that and uninstall first.